# verify if email is delivered successfully nodemailer (sails.js)

Tags: javascript, sails.js, email-client, nodemailer

I'm using [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) module to send email in my sails.js project. Now i'm wondering if there is a way that i could know if the email is delivered successfully or the email is somehow failed due to some attachment or may be wrong email address.

how can i make it sure that the email address is valid or not ? or the email is being delivered to the relevant email address successfully or not ?

I've read the nodemailer documentation and also have done some R&D on it but so far i'm not able to find anything productive.

Please let me know if there is a way to confirm about email or not.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way you can do that, in general, short of asking the recipient to click on a link.

Answer (score 10):

It's simple. `sendMail` has a callback as an argument. You just checking if some error is exists in this callback.

```
transport.sendMail({}, (error, result) => {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  return console.log(result);
});
```

Or you can use `sails-service-mailer` package for sending mails - https://github.com/ghaiklor/sails-service-mailer. Then you can write your code like this

```
SmtpMailer
  .send({})
  .then(console.log.bind(console))
  .catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

If you want to check pool or something then there is no possibility, I suppose. If you send mail to non-existing email address it sends as usual, just not be received by recipient. Anyway, you can check if mail was added to pool only.

**UPD:** `transport` has a Promise API as well (see https://nodemailer.com/usage/) so there is no need in custom wrappers like mine `sails-service-mailer` anymore.

Comment: What about sending email confirmations or password reset by email? Can you help me implementing this in Sails?

Comment: It seems `transport.sendMail` is also wrapped with a Promise object, if you don't add a callback to `sendMail` -> according to [these docs](https://nodemailer.com/usage/)

Comment: If there is no `err` it just means the mail was sent. This says nothing about whether the mail was **delivered**.

Comment: @Mythos is right, the resolve object from sendmail doesn't include anything about whether the mail was received or not. as far as it's sent successfully it doesn't concern itself whether the email is existent or not

Comment: I've been trying to achieve thesame thing by first sending the verification mail to a user, making sure they received it before saving them in the DB but I haven't found solution yet. Can you please share the solution here If You've found any

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there might be two solutions here.

One is described here: https://nodemailer.com/smtp/dsn/

> DELIVERY STATUS NOTIFICATIONS
>
> If your delivery service supports it (not all SMTP servers have DSN
> extension enabled), then you can use Delivery status notifications
> (DSN) with Nodemailer as defined in RFC3461.

Examples

1.Request DSN for delivered messages

```
let message = {
    from: 'sender@example.com',
    to: 'recipient@example.com',
    subject: 'Message',
    text: 'I hope this message gets read!',
    dsn: {
        id: 'some random message specific id',
        return: 'headers',
        notify: 'success',
        recipient: 'sender@example.com'
    }
};
```

2.Request DSN for undelivered and delayed messages

```
let message = {
    from: 'sender@example.com',
    to: 'recipient@example.com',
    subject: 'Message',
    text: 'I hope this message gets read!',
    dsn: {
        id: 'some random message specific id',
        return: 'headers',
        notify: ['failure', 'delay'],
        recipient: 'sender@example.com'
    }
};
```

Another option is discussed in github here: https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/487

> The "standard" bounce handling is to use VERP, eg. to use a custom
> FROM address for the SMTP envelope and then listen for messages for
> this address – if anything is received then the message has bounced.

```
mailOptions = {
    from: 'sender@mydomain.com',
    to: 'receiver@example.com',
    messageId: 'abcdef',
    envelope: {
        from: 'abcdef+receiver+example.com@bounces.mydomain.com',
        to: ['receiver@example.com']
    }
}
```

> The smtp-server would listen for incoming messages, accept everything
> but storing nothing. Once a message is received, it checks the TO
> address and if the address is
> abcdef+receiver+example.com@bounces.mydomain.com then it can emit an
> event that a message with message-id 'abcdef' to receiver@example.com
> was bounced. You should also look into the message body to see the
> reason but this is probably quite difficult as every server software
> uses a different format for bounce messages.

And then you'd need to monitor inbox and handle the bounce emails.